# React with Express application using "pm2 start" always shows status as errored

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, package.json, pm2

I have a React app with Node as the server and I am writing my code in ES6 and transpiled using babel. I am using **Windows OS**. I was using NodeMon for watching changes it worked fine in development. I am making a production configuration for the app and thought of using PM2 for both dev and prod.

Below is the script in my package.json,

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "pm2 start --watch --interpreter babel-node src/server/server.js  --name appDev",
    ...
    "prod": "pm2 start build/server/server.js -i max --name appProd"
  }
```

I have ES6 code in my src folder and transpiled ES5 code in build folder. "prod" command works fine if I remove "-i max" [infinite command prompts started opening up with "-i max". Hope it will be fine in server after deployment].

Now the problem is, "dev" script is always resulting in "errored" status and when I check status error logs are empty.

ANy idea what's going on? I will run NodeMon in dev and PM2 in prod for now but why PM2 has issue with ES6 and --interpreter babel-node?

**Update:**
I have tried `--interpreter babel-cli` after installing globally, it failed with an error `[PM2][ERROR] Interpreter babel-cli does not seem to be available`. I have babel-cli globally and locally.

Even `pm2 start app.js --interpreter ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues deploying with the latest (12.16.2) version of node.  I was having issues with ES6 and imports.  I understand there are more complex solutions that can solve that issue, but backing up to node 12.4.0 solved that issue for me.  NOTE: Node 12.4.0 is an earlier release than 12.16.2.  I picked version 12.4.0 because that is what Digital Oceans "Node" servers are initialized with.  I figured that their server guys probably know far more about it than I, and just decided to cheat off their test, so to speak.

I am having no issues with 12.4.0, and you can easily download an earlier version off of the node website.  If you plan to install it on a Linux server, I would recommend using nvm.  I had used nvm to go back to 12.4.0, and still had issues (I am sorry I forget specifics).  I just redid the server from a fresh image with plain Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and am good on that at this time.  Even with the local Windows install of node that I use to develop, I had to do a full uninstall and a clean install to avoid issues.  Highly recommend this route if able.

Good luck.